# Combining Minimum Requirements_CPU and Memory

Tags: memory, cpu, computer-building

I'm in the process of figuring out how to build a VM to use the minimum necessary resources to run what I need it to run and I'm trying to understand how to combine system requirements.

It seems to me that Disk requirements would be simple addition: 20 GB disk requirement + 50 GB disk requirement means a minimum of 60 GB disk. However, I suspect that listed requirements for CPUs and Memory don't work that way.

For instance, if the OS I'm using requires 2 vCPUs and 2 GB Memory and the program I need to run requires 4 vCPUs and 2.5 GB memory, I don't think that my minimal VM would need 6 vCPUs and 4.5 GB Memory. However, if the OS and program need to run processes simultaneously, I'm worried that 4 vCPUs and 2.5 GB memory will be insufficient to support a stable platform. I've been googling various versions of this question, but haven't found anything useful yet, and I didn't see any questions here that focused on how two programs with distinct sets of requirements for CPU and Memory actually relate to one another.

How would these sets of requirements relate to one another in practice? I'm not entirely sure if this is relevant, the OS I'm looking at supports hyper-threading, but the program I want to run does not.

Comment: You set the memory and CPU to the amount you need to run the software on the VM. It appears you are making a very simple process, overcomplicated, it really is that simple.

Comment: Build the VM with a best guess set of resources and then monitor actual utilization. Adjust up or down as necessary and remember that you want to scale to the peak usage, not the average. Vendor requirements are also guesses on their part and are usually inflated to make sure enough resources are present.

Comment: Thanks! I probably am overthinking it @Ramhound. I've been thinking that since I started trying to figure this out. I think what is throwing me is the need to be as close as possible to the minimum necessary. Should be a simple project and I'm overthinking everything.

Comment: @doneal24, that's helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce CPUs it will just run *slower*.
Memory might choke, though, & assigning too little will see it paging into your VM's VHD a lot… which will be slower than slow.

Assuming you have plenty of real RAM to spare & a decent multi-core CPU, then the 'most efficient' for a speedy VM is 'the number of real cores' & 16GB RAM [8 at a pinch]. Less & you'll eventually start to get slow-downs, as above.

I don't have any figures for this, it's just empiricism in action ;)